# Going back to viewController that was already segued to and is already loaded? No nav controller

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

How can I go back to a viewController that was already segued from another VC without Nav Controller embed?

Meaning I have viewController A which segued to viewController B.  I dismissed viewController B and now back at viewController A.  How can I go back to the same instance of viewController B?

I've looked at a lot of SO posts but they all seemed to be about unwinding, which would work if I want to go from B back to A, but not back to B again.

Also, viewController A is in a tabbar.  Viewcontoller B is not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a segue, since segues always instantiate new controllers. Instead of a segue, you should create a property for ViewControllerB in ViewControllerA, and instantiate it only the first time you go to it (which you would do using presentViewController:animated:completion). After coming back to A, when you want to go to B again present the instance you already created. If you're using a storyboard to make your controllers, you would do something like this,

```
-(void)someMethod {
    if (!self.vcB) { // vcB is a strong property
        self.vcB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCB"];
    }

    [self presentViewController:vcB animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! however, I'm a little confused between the explanation and the code provided...the explanation say to instantiate VCB, as it would have been the VC i segue to, but in the code, it's instantiating VCA?  I understand that in VCA, I should make @property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController* VCB, and instantiate it the first time.  Right?

Comment: YESSSS!!! THANK YOUUUU!! Saved my 4 more hours of pointless coding and band-aid solutions!  But I followed your original explanation!

Comment: @TuanAnhVu, sorry, that was a typo. It should be vcB. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a reference to VC B:

```
var VCB:UIViewController = bInstance
```

Then you will want to dismiss VCB from VCA

```
VCA.dismissViewController(VCB,animated:false)
```

Then to bring it back you go:

```
VCA.presentViewController(VCB,animated:false)
```

Keep in mind that the new compiler for Xcode uses ARC which does automatic reference counting. You need to keep a reference to the UIViewController to bring it back, otherwise it gets deleted!

Comment: hm.  how can  I grab a reference to VCB if it's not attached to a Nav Controller or Tabbar?  i guess, that was the underlying question is how can i grab a reference to VCB...thanks